# Why is a pushforward of a $\sigma$-finite measure not necessarily $\sigma$-finite?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

What is an example that shows that if $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on $\Omega$ and $T:\Omega\to\Omega'$ is measurable then $\mu \cdot T^{-1}$ is not necessarily $\sigma$-finite? I have a basic understanding of what $\sigma$-finite means but if $\mu$ is finite that implies $\mu \cdot T^{-1}$ is finite, so why isn't this also true for $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: Does not imply what, where $T$ is what?

Comment: sorry about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure on set $\Omega$ with $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B$, and $T$ is a measurable mapping from $(\Omega, \mathcal B)$ into $(\Omega', \mathcal B')$ where $\mathcal B'$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega'$.  Then $\mu \circ T^{-1}$ is a measure on $(\Omega',\mathcal B')$.

For example, take $\Omega = \Omega' = \mathbb Z$ with $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal B$ consisting of all subsets of $\mathbb Z$, $T$ the identity map, and $\mu$ counting measure, but let $\mathcal B'$ be the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\{\emptyset, \Omega'\}$.  $\mu \circ T^{-1}$ is not $\sigma$-finite because no nonempty members of $\mathcal B'$ have finite measure.

Comment: Thanks this really helps. I would vote this up but I do not have the required reputation.